# How to serve multiple domains from the same code base in Play Framework 2.1 (Scala)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

Using Scala under Play Framework 2.1 I want to serve multiple domains using the same code base and database. Can't find anything on this for the latest version under Scala.

I'm building a multi-site CMS sort of like Magento and need to be able to detect the domain/hostname and pull a different entry from the database based on the domain being requested.

How do I detect which domain is being requested within Scala so I can serve the proper content?

I was thinking something like this in Global.scala could work:

```
import play.api._

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {
    //detect domain host here
    //set global variable for which domain to use when interacting with the DB
  }

}
```

Or would this be something that needs to be handled in the routes file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `play.api.mvc.Call.absoluteURL` method to retrieve the full URL of a controller.

As example:

```
val url = controllers.routes.Index.view().absoluteURL()
```

You need a implicit RequestHeader in scope for this call. I think the best solution to detect the URL globally, is to use the [filter API](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaInterceptors).